# In Python, can you call an instance method of class A, but pass in an instance of class B?

Tags: python, oop, coding-style

In the interest of reusing some existing code that was defined as an instance method of a different class, I was tying to do something like the following:

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = "Foo"

  def hello(self):
    print "Hello, I am " + self.name + "."

class Bar(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = "Bar"


bar = Bar()
Foo.hello(bar)
```

but that results in:

> TypeError: unbound method hello() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got Bar instance instead)

Is something like this possible?

---

I should have been clear that I know this is a bad idea. Obviously the real solution is a bit of refactoring. I just figured there must be a way, and it turns out there is.

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Looks like Python gave you your answer.  This is the wrong approach for reusing existing code, anyway.

Comment: Why don't you want to factor out the common functionality and call it from the instance methods of both Foo and Bar?

Comment: Yes, this is clearly the wrong approach. I just assumed it could be done due to Python's dynamic nature, and was a little surprised when it didn't work as I expected.

Comment: -1: This approach is so unsound it gives me the willies.  If it can be done, it should be prohibited as being intentionally misleading.

Comment: remember that Python is strongly typed and originated at a [centre for mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrum_Wiskunde_%26_Informatica).  not surprisingly it signals a TypeError!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this works:

```
Foo.hello.im_func(bar)
```

> Hello, I am Bar.

I guess I need to read a [this](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) little harder...

Comment: Yeah, but that's something you should never be doing (except to learn how it works).

Comment: Interesting find.  But agree that it would be inappropriate to use it for the question asked here.

Comment: I don't intend to actually use it. It was just a "how does this work" question. I'll add a note to the original question.

Comment: There may be a legitimate case for using this.  This should be the accepted answer of this question.

Answer (score 5):

It happens because python wraps class functions as an "unbound method" which performs this type checking.  There's some description of the decisions involved in this [here](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/first-class-everything.html).

Note that this type checking has actually been dropped in python 3 (see the note at the end of that article), so your approach will work there.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but Python has evolved and looks like it's worth pointing it out:

with Python 3 there's no more `<unbound method C.x>`, since an unbound method is simply a `<function __main__.C.x>`!

Which probably means the code in the original question should not be considered /that/ off. Python has always been about duck typing in any case, hasn't it?!

### Refs:

- [Guido proposing to remove unbound methods from python](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-January/050625.html)
- [What's new](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods) for Python 3 release
- [Get defining class of unbound method object in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589311/get-defining-class-of-unbound-method-object-in-python-3)

### Alternative solution in Py2

Note that there's also an alternative solution to the "explorative" question (see [Python: Bind an Unbound Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015307/python-bind-an-unbound-method)):

```
In [6]: a = A.a.im_func.__get__(B(), B)

In [7]: a
Out[7]: <bound method B.a of <__main__.B instance at 0x7f37d81a1ea8>>

In [8]: a(2)
2
```

Ref:

## Some ipython code samples

### python 2

```
In [1]: class A():
    def a(self, a=0):
        print a
   ...:

In [2]: A.a
Out[2]: <unbound method A.a>

In [3]: A.a.im_func
Out[3]: <function __main__.a>

In [4]: A.a(B())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7694121f3429> in <module>()
----> 1 A.a(B())

TypeError: unbound method a() must be called with A instance as first argument (got B instance instead)
```

### python 3

```
In [2]: class A():
    def a(self, a=0):
        print(a)
   ...:

In [3]: def a():
   ...:     pass
   ...:

In [4]: class B():
   ...:     pass

In [5]: A.a(B())
0

In [6]: A.a
Out[6]: <function __main__.A.a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A while back I wondered about the same "feature" in Perl on PerlMonks, and the [general consensus](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=432172) was that while it works (as it does in Python) you should not be doing things that way.