# How to bind an unbound method without calling it?

Tags: python, class, methods, bind

In Python, is there a way to bind an unbound method without calling it?

I am writing a wxPython program, and for a certain class I decided it would be nice to group the data of all of my buttons together as a class-level list of tuples, like so:

```
class MyWidget(wx.Window):
    buttons = [
        ("OK", OnOK),
        ("Cancel", OnCancel)
    ]
 
    ...

    def setup(self):
        for text, handler in MyWidget.buttons:
            # This following line is the problem line.
            b = wx.Button(parent, label=text).bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, handler)
```

The problem is, since all of the values of `handler` are unbound methods, my program explodes in a spectacular blaze and I weep.

I was looking around online for a solution to what seems like should be a relatively straightforward, solvable problem. Unfortunately I couldn’t find anything. Right now, I am using `functools.partial` to work around this, but does anyone know if there’s a clean-feeling, healthy, Pythonic way to bind an unbound method to an instance and continue passing it around without calling it?

Comment: @Christopher - A method that isn't bound to the scope of the object it was sucked from, so you have to pass self explicitly.

Comment: I particularly like "spectacular blaze and I weep."

Answer (score 215, accepted):

All functions are also *descriptors*, so you can bind them by calling their `__get__` method:

```
bound_handler = handler.__get__(self, MyWidget)
```

Here's R. Hettinger's excellent [guide](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) to descriptors.

---

As a self-contained example pulled from [Keith's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/834176/keith-pinson) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015307/python-bind-an-unbound-method#comment8431145_1015405):

```
def bind(instance, func, as_name=None):
    """
    Bind the function *func* to *instance*, with either provided name *as_name*
    or the existing name of *func*. The provided *func* should accept the 
    instance as the first argument, i.e. "self".
    """
    if as_name is None:
        as_name = func.__name__
    bound_method = func.__get__(instance, instance.__class__)
    setattr(instance, as_name, bound_method)
    return bound_method

class Thing:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

something = Thing(21)

def double(self):
    return 2 * self.val

bind(something, double)
something.double()  # returns 42
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. I like how you can omit the type and get back a "bound method ?.f" instead.

Comment: I like this solution over the `MethodType` one, because it works the same in py3k, while `MethodType`'s arguments have been changed up a bit.

Comment: And thus, a function to bind functions to class instances:
`bind = lambda instance, func, asname: setattr(instance, asname, func.__get__(instance, instance.__class__))`
Example:
`class A: pass;`
`a = A();`
`bind(a, bind, 'bind')`

Comment: Huh, you learn something new every day. @Kazark In Python 3, at least, you can also skip supplying the type, as `__get__` will take that implicitly from the object parameter. I'm not even sure if supplying it does anything, as it makes no difference what type I supply as the second parameter regardless of what the first parameter is an instance of. So `bind = lambda instance, func, asname=None: setattr(instance, asname or func.__name__, func.__get__(instance))` should do the trick as well. (Though I'd prefer having `bind` usable as a decorator, personally, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: I just learned that functions are also descriptors for the first time thanks to @AlexMartelli

Comment: You sir are awesome. I have been looking for a way to fix this for the last couple of weeks. Finally came up with the right search terms and you solved my anguish in one brief line and a link to some great docs. I can now configure my logging to a ridiculous extent, not just by adding new level methods to the Logger class, but specific methods for specific instances.

Comment: Just to clarify, is it OK to do `handler.__get__(self, type(self))`? Is there ever a context when you would not want to make the second parameter `type(self)`?

Comment: Wow, never knew functions were descriptors. That's a very elegant design, methods are just plain functions in the class' `__dict__` and attribute access gives you unbound or bound methods through the normal descriptor protocol. I always assumed it was some sort of magic that happened during `type.__new__()`

Comment: @MadPhysicist It’s okay but unnecessary to provide the second `owner` argument as it’s not used by functions’ `__get__` method. The only context I’m aware of where the `owner` parameter is used is in `classmethod`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66767084/2326961) for more details.

Answer (score 97):

This can be done with [`types.MethodType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MethodType):

```py
import types

bound_handler = types.MethodType(handler, self)
```

Comment: +1 This is awesome, but there's no reference to it in the python docs at the URL you provided.

Comment: +1, I prefer not to have calls to magic functions in my code (i.e. `__get__`). I don't know for which version of python this you tested this on, but on python 3.4, the `MethodType` function takes two arguments. The function and the instance. So this should be changed to `types.MethodType(f, C())`.

Comment: Here it is! It's a good way to patch instance methods: `wgt.flush = types.MethodType(lambda self: None, wgt)`

Comment: It is actually mentioned in the docs, but in the descriptor page from the other answer: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods

Answer (score 12):

With a [*closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), also known as a *closed expression* (as opposed to an *open expression*), which is an expression without [free variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables):

```py
bound_handler = (lambda handler, self:
    lambda *args, **kwargs: handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
)(handler, self)
```

Here `handler` and `self` are free variables in the inner lambda expression and [bound variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) in the outer lambda expression, and `args` and `kwargs` are bound variables in both the inner and outer lambda expressions, so the outer lambda expression is a closure.

Comment: Yes, this is about the same as my original fix, which was to use `functools.partial(handler, self)`

Answer (score 10):

This will bind `self` to `handler`:

```py
bound_handler = lambda *args, **kwargs: handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

This works by passing `self` as the first argument to the function. `obj.f()` is just syntactic sugar for `f(obj)`.

Comment: Yes, but this calls the method. The problem is I need to be able to pass the bound method as a callable object. I have the unbound method and the instance I'd like it to be bound to, but can't figure out how to put it all together without immediately calling it

Comment: No it doesn't, it'll only call the method if you do bound_handler(). Defining a lambda does not call the lambda.

Comment: You could actually use `functools.partial` instead of defining a lambda. It doesn't solve the exact problem, though. You're still dealing with a `function` instead of an `instancemethod`.

Comment: @Alan: what's the difference between a `function` whose first argument you partial-ed and `instancemethod`; duck typing can't see the difference.

Comment: @LieRyan the difference is that you're still not dealing with the fundamental type. `functools.partial` drops some metadata, e.g. `__module__`. (Also I wanna state for the record I cringe real hard when I look at my first comment on this answer.)

In fact in my question I mention I'm already using `functools.partial` but I felt like there had to be a "purer" way, since it's easy to get both unbound and bound methods.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I came here with a similar question: I have a class method and an instance, and want to apply the instance to the method.

At the risk of oversimplifying the OP's question, I ended up doing something less mysterious that may be useful to others who arrive here (caveat: I'm working in Python 3 -- YMMV).

Consider this simple class:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def value(self):
        return self._value

    def set_value(self, value):
        self._value = value
```

Here's what you can do with it:

```
>>> meth = Foo.set_value   # the method
>>> a = Foo(12)            # a is an instance with value 12
>>> meth(a, 33)            # apply instance and method
>>> a.value()              # voila - the method was called
33
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue - which is that I wanted `meth` to be invokable without having to send it the `a` argument (which is why I initially used `functools.partial`) - but this is preferable if you don't need to pass the method around and can just invoke it on the spot.  Also this works the same way in Python 2 as it does in Python 3.

Comment: Apologies for not reading your original requirements more carefully.  I am partial (pun intended) to the lambda-based approach given by @brian-brazil in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1015355/558639 -- it's about as pure as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [@Keith Pinson’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7312062/2326961) which uses a closure and [@brian-brazil’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1015355/2326961) which does not, here is why the former is correct.

Example with a closure:

```py
def handler(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self


self = True
bound_handler = (lambda handler, self:
    lambda *args, **kwargs: handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
)(handler, self)
bound_handler()  # returns True
self = False
bound_handler()  # returns True
handler = print
bound_handler()  # returns True
```

The outer lambda expression is closed so its bound variables `handler` and `self` cannot be rebound. `__get__`, `types.MethodType`, and `functools.partial` have the same behaviour.

Example without a closure:

```py
def handler(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self


self = True
bound_handler = lambda *args, **kwargs: handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
bound_handler()  # returns True
self = False
bound_handler()  # returns False
handler = print
bound_handler()  # prints False
```

The lambda expression is open so its free variables `handler` and `self` can be rebound.