# Are there functions in Python, or is everything a method?

Tags: python, function, oop, methods

Or is everything a method?

Since everything is an object, a

```
def whatever:
```

is just a method of that file.py, right?

Comment: and I thought function and method are synonymous to each other.

Comment: @Amarghosh: No. Methods are descriptors bound to a class.

Comment: Terminology varies among languages I believe - in java everything is a method - static or instance.

Comment: Java is slightly unusual in that regard, in that it lacks functions that aren't methods. (ie. Functions that aren't bound to a class.)

Comment: +1 good question, it touches fundamental and deep Python topics.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Python has functions.  As everything is an object [functions are objects too](http://www.diveintopython.org/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html).

So, to use your example:

```
>>> def whatever():
...     pass
...
>>> whatever
<function whatever at 0x00AF5F30>
```

When we use `def` we have created an object which is a function.  We can, for example, look at an attribute of the object:

```
>>> whatever.func_name
'whatever'
```

In answer to your question - `whatever()` is **not** a *method* of `file.py`.  It is better to think of it as a function object bound to the name `whatever` in the global namespace of `file.py`.

```
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__d
oc__': None, 'whatever': <function whatever at 0x00AF5EB0>}
```

Or to look at it another way, there's nothing stopping us from binding the name `whatever` to a different object altogether:

```
>>> whatever
<function whatever at 0x00AF5F30>
>>> whatever = "string"
>>> whatever
'string'
```

There are other ways to create function objects.  For example, [lambdas](http://www.diveintopython.org/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html):

```
>>> somelambda = lambda x: x * 2
>>> somelambda
<function <lambda> at 0x00AF5F30>
```

A method is like attribute of an object that is a function.  What makes it a method is that the methods get bound to the object.  This causes the object to get passed to the function as the first argument which we normally call `self`.

Let's define a class `SomeClass` with a method `somemethod` and an instance `someobject`:

```
>>> class SomeClass:
...     def somemethod(one="Not Passed", two="Not passed"):
...         print "one = %s\ntwo = %s" % (one,two)
...
>>> someobject = SomeClass()
```

Let's look at `somemethod` as an attribute:

```
>>> SomeClass.somemethod
<unbound method SomeClass.somemethod>
>>> someobject.somemethod
<bound method SomeClass.somemethod of <__main__.SomeClass instance at 0x00AFE030
```

We can see it's a bound method on the object and an unbound method on the class.  So now let's call the method and see what happens:

```
>>> someobject.somemethod("Hello world")
one = <__main__.SomeClass instance at 0x00AFE030>
two = Hello world
```

As it's a bound method the first argument received by `somemethod` is the object and the second argument is the first argument in the method call.  Let's call the method on the class:

```
>>> SomeClass.somemethod("Hello world")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method somemethod() must be called with SomeClass instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Python complains because we're trying to call the method without giving it an object of the appropriate type.  So we can fix this by passing the object "by hand":

```
>>> SomeClass.somemethod(someobject,"Hello world")
one = <__main__.SomeClass instance at 0x00AFE030>
two = Hello world
```

You might use method calls of this type - calling a method on a class - when you want to call a specific method from a superclass.

(It is possible to [take a function and bind it to class to make it a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015307/python-bind-an-unbound-method), but this is not something that you'd normally ever need to do.)

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in Java in Python a file named `file.py` does not necessarily contain a class called `file` as you might expect if this was a java file named `file.java`.

In Python a file is a module which is really just a namespace (more comparable to a Java package than a Java class) and not a class. Consider the example `file.py` below:

```
def whatever_func():
    print "What ever function"

class SomeClass(object):
    def whatever_meth(self):
        print "What ever method"
```

In the example above the `file` module/namespace contains an ordinary function named `whatever_func` and a class `SomeClass` which has a method `whatever_meth`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... You can work with "whatever" as an ordinary function in file namespace.