# Why does a python descriptor __get__ method accept the owner class as an arg?

Tags: python

Why does the `__get__` method in a [python descriptor](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) accept the owner class as it's third argument? Can you give an example of it's use?

The first argument (`self`) is self evident, the second (`instances`) makes sense in the context of the typically shown descriptor pattern (ex to follow), but I've never really seen the third (`owner`) used. Can someone explain what the use case is for it?

Just by way of reference and facilitating answers this is the typical use of descriptors I've seen:

```
class Container(object):
    class ExampleDescriptor(object):
        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
            return instance._name 
        def __set__(self, instance, value):
            instance._name = value
    managed_attr = ExampleDescriptor()
```

Given that `instance.__class__` is available all I can think of is that explicitly passing the class has something to do with directly accessing the descriptor from the class instead of an instances (ex `Container.managed_attr`). Even so I'm not clear on what one would do in `__get__` in this situation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`owner` is used when the attribute is accessed from the class instead of an instance of the class, in which case `instance` will be `None`.

In your example attempting something like `print(Container.managed_attr)` would fail because `instance` is `None` so `instance._name` would raise an `AttributeError`.

You could improve this behavior by checking to see if `instance is None`, and it may be useful for logging or raising a more helpful exception to know which class the descriptor belongs to, hence the `owner` attribute.  For example:

```
        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
            if instance is None:
                # special handling for Customer.managed_attr
            else:
                return instance._name
```

Comment: "logging or raising a more helpful exception" Thanks.

Comment: Why not to also implement managed class level attributes? For example, when an existing class data attribute would benefit from being seen in different units. Say, Room.default_temperature_C, Room.default_temperature_F? Isn't it the more obvious use case, or am I missing something?

Comment: @max: you are missing something ;) -- ask it as a regular question if you want a detailed answer.

Comment: The OP in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63380778/2326961) made an insightful suggestion: the same functionality could be achieved with a single argument `instance` always bound to the originating object, regardless of whether the originating object is a class instance or a class (i.e. a metaclass instance). If that information is really needed, one could just check using `isinstance(instance, type)`. So I’m not sure anymore your answer is valid.

Answer (score 2):

When the descriptor is accessed from the class, `instance` will be `None`.  If you have not accounted for that situation (as your example code does not) then an error will occur at that point.

What *should* you do in that case?  Whatever is sensible.  ;)  If nothing else makes sense you could follow `property`'s example and return the descriptor itself when accessed from the class.

Comment: Any chance you can explain how returning the descriptor is sensible for property?

Comment: @Finn: *Something* is there, so *something* should be returned.  Since there is no instance to get a value from, the descriptor object is the next best choice.  If you had a custom descriptor with an actual (default) class value, then you should return that when accessed via the class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's used so that the descriptor can see Container when Container.managed_attr is accessed. You could return some object appropriate to the use case, like an unbound method when descriptors are used to implement methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most famous application of the `owner` parameter of the `__get__` method in Python is the [`classmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods). Here is a pure Python version:

```py
import types

class ClassMethod:
    "Emulate PyClassMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c."

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None and owner is None:
            raise TypeError("__get__(None, None) is invalid")
        if owner is None:
            owner = type(instance)
        if hasattr(self.f, "__get__"):
            return self.f.__get__(owner)
        return types.MethodType(self.f, owner)
```

`classmethod` binds the first parameter of a function to a *subclass* of the class *owning* the `classmethod` instance that is found during an attribute lookup *originating* from an object. The resulting callable of this binding is a method. To derive that subclass from the originating object, `classmethod` need know whether the originating object is an instance (in which case it uses the type of the instance provided by the `instance` parameter) or a subclass of the owning class (in which case it directly uses the subclass provided by the `owner` parameter). That information is provided by the `instance` parameter which is `None` in the former and not `None` in the latter. So `classmethod` works for attribute lookup originating from instances but also from subclasses thanks to the `owner` parameter:

```py
class A:

    @ClassMethod
    def name(cls):
        return cls.__name__


A().name()  # returns 'A' so attribute lookup from an instance works
A.name()    # returns 'A' so attribute lookup from a class works too
```

More information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66790797/2326961).