# Binding External Methods that Need to Access Private Variables: Feature or Bug?

Tags: python, cpython

**SHORT VERSION**: External methods bound to an instance can't access private variables directly via `self.__privatevarname`. Is this a feature or a bug?

**EXTENDED VERSION (WITH EXPLANATION AND EXAMPLE)**:

In [Python: Bind an Unbound Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1015405/1068170), Alex Martelli explains a simple method for binding a function to an instance.

Using this method, one can use external functions to set instance methods in a class (in `__init__`).

However, this breaks down when the function being bound to the instance needs to access private variables. This is because the name mangling occurs during the the [compile](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bdc7ad1f05ef/Python/compile.c#l206) step in `_Py_Mangle`, and so the function never has a chance to call `__getattribute__('_classname__privatevarname')`.

For example, if we define a simple external addition function that accesses the private instance variable `__obj_val`:

```
def add_extern(self, value):
  return self.__obj_val + value
```

and bind it to each instance in `__init__` while also defining a similar instance method `add_intern` in the class definition

```
class TestClass(object):
  def __init__(self, object_value):
    self.__obj_val = object_value
    self.add_extern = add_extern.__get__(self, TestClass)

  def add_intern(self, value):
    return self.__obj_val + value
```

then the internal method will work but the external bound method will raise an exception:

```
>>> t = TestClass(0)
>>> t.add_intern(1)
1
>>> t.add_extern(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in add_extern
AttributeError: 'TestClass' object has no attribute '__obj_val'
```

**POSTSCRIPT**: You can overcome this shortcoming by overriding `__getattribute__` to do the mangling for you:

```
class TestClass(object):
  ...
  def __getattribute__(self, name):
    try:
      return super(TestClass, self).__getattribute__(name)
    except AttributeError:
      # mimic behavior of _Py_Mangle
      if not name.startswith('__'):  # only private attrs
        raise
      if name.endswith('__'):  # don't mangle dunder attrs
        raise
      if '.' in name:  # don't mangle for modules
        raise
      if not name.lstrip('_'):  # don't mangle if just underscores
        raise

      mangled_name = '_{cls_name}{attr_name}'.format(
          cls_name=self.__class__.__name__, attr_name=name)
      return super(TestClass, self).__getattribute__(mangled_name)
```

However, this doesn't leave the variables private to external callers, which we don't want.

Answer (score 2):

Due to Python's [name-mangling](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5/tut/node67.html), the actual name of the attribute as stored on `t` is `_TestClass__obj_val` (as you can see in `dir(t)`). The external function, not having been defined on a class, is just looking for `__obj_val`.

The mangled name is stored in the function's code object (e.g. `t.add_extern.func_code.co_names`) and is read-only, so there's no easy way to update it.

So there's a reason not to use that technique... at least with mangled names.

Comment: I'm 100% aware of all of this. I am curious if this is a feature or a bug. The action of binding the function to the instance is in some ways an incomplete bind without it, so IMO it's a bug. It really is a corner case though, so it's no big deal.

Comment: Oh, well, in *that* case. Yeah, looks like a bug, but I don't think creating new instance methods is documented anyway. Clearly the name-mangling stuff is in the function constructor instead of in the method constructor where it belongs.