# Python dynamic class methods

Tags: python, runtime, class-method

Say there is:

```
class A(B):
    ...
```

where `B` could be `object` and `...` is **not**:

```
@classmethod # or @staticmethod
def c(cls): print 'Hello from c!'
```

What do I have to do that calling `A.c()` wont trigger `AttributeError`?

In other words, I know it is possible to manually add class methods to a class at runtime. But is it possible to do so automatically, say every time a class method is missing it creates some dummy method?

In yet another words, only if I could replace `A.__dict__` with my dict which handles `__getitem__` - but `A.__dict__` seems to be not writable...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a [`__getattr__` hook](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) on a [metaclass](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation).

```
class DefaultClassMethods(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, attr):
        def _defaultClassMethod(cls):
            print 'Hi, I am the default class method!'
        setattr(cls, attr, classmethod(_defaultClassMethod))
        return getattr(cls, attr)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class DefaultClassMethods(type):
...     def __getattr__(cls, attr):
...         def _defaultClassMethod(cls):
...             print 'Hi, I am the default class method!'
...         setattr(cls, attr, classmethod(_defaultClassMethod))
...         return getattr(cls, attr)
... 
>>> class A(object):
...     __metaclass__ = DefaultClassMethods
... 
>>> A.spam
<bound method DefaultClassMethods._defaultClassMethod of <class '__main__.A'>>
>>> A.spam()
Hi, I am the default class method!
```

Note that we set the result of the `classmethod` call straight onto the class, effectively caching it for future lookups.

If you need to regenerate the class method on every call instead, use the same [method to bind a function to an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015307/python-bind-an-unbound-method) but with the class and metaclass instead (using `cls.__metaclass__` to be consistent with metaclass subclassing):

```
from types import MethodType

class DefaultClassMethods(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, attr):
        def _defaultClassMethod(cls):
            print 'Hi, I am the default class method!'
        return _defaultClassMethod.__get__(cls, cls.__metaclass__)
```

For static methods just return the function directly in all cases, no need to muck with the `staticmethod` decorator or the descriptor protocol.

Comment: A.asd() - AttributeError: "type object 'A' has no attribute 'asd'"

Comment: I want spam to be class method, not instance method.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviors provided to instances by methods like `__getattr__` and the descriptor protocol can work for classes as well, but in that case, you have to code them in the class's metaclass.

In this case, all one needs to do is to set the metaclass `__getattr__` function to auto-generate the desired class attribute.

(The setattr, getattr trick is to let Python do the function->method transoform with no need to mess with it)

```
class AutoClassMethod(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, attr):
        default = classmethod(lambda cls: "Default class method for " + repr(cls))
        setattr(cls, attr, default)
        return getattr(cls, attr)



class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = AutoClassMethod
    @classmethod
    def b(cls):
        print cls
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> class C(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> C.m = classmethod(lambda cls: cls.__name__)
>>> C.m()
'C'
```

Or you can use somethigs like this:

```
class Wrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, clz, default=lambda cls: None):
        self._clz = clz
        self._default = default

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # __attrs__ will be getted from Wrapper
        if attr.startswith('__'):
            return self.__getattribute__(attr)

        if not hasattr(self._clz, attr):
            setattr(self._clz, attr, classmethod(self._default))
        return getattr(self._clz, attr)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._clz(*args, **kwargs)

>>> class C(object):
...     pass
...
>>> C = Wrapper(C, default=lambda cls: cls.__name__)
>>> c = C()
>>> print C.m()
'C'
>>> print c.m() # now instance have method "m"
'C'
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know you can add class methods manually. Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: @EcirHana, python instantiate class-objects on module import. And this class-objects do not have method `__getattribute__` or some equivalent...