# Find name of dynamic method in Python

Tags: python, runtime, introspection, class-method

I want to proxy an API over a network.  I have the API in a dictionary.  I'd like to create a class with the API methods from the dictionary so I can use the API as if I was local.  The trouble is finding the name of my dynamically created method.  (My approach is based on [Adding a Method to an Existing Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object) and [Python dynamic class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281698/python-dynamic-class-methods).)

```
class MainClass(object):
    def build_API(self):
        methods = dict(meth1='arg1', meth2='arg2')
        for key in methods.iterkeys():
            setattr(self, key, MethodType(self.default_API, self))
    def default_API(self, *args, **kwargs)
        called_as_name = ????
        self.send_message(called_as_name, args, kwargs)
    def send_message(self, called_as_name, *args, **kwargs)
        ...
        # Send API command over network
        ....
```

To use this:

```
api = MainClass()
api.build_API()
api.meth1()
```

However, everything I try for "called_as_name" always returns "default_API" and never "meth1".  How can I get "called_as_name = meth1" when I type "api.meth1()" and "called_as_name = meth2" when I type "api.meth2()"?

I have tried:

```
curframe = inspect.currentframe()
calframe = inspect.getouterframes(curframe, 2)
called_as_name = calframe[1][3]
```

from [Python: How to get the caller's method name in the called method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2654130/3571110)

```
called_as_name = inspect.stack()[1][5]
```

from [Getting the caller function name inside another function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/900404/3571110)

```
called_as_name = sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name
```

from [Getting the caller function name inside another function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/900413/3571110)

Comment: You'd be better off making `meth1` and `meth2` be some sort of fake callable object that stores its own name.  Also, I don't really think what you're doing is a good idea.  All you're doing is making a bunch of aliases to a single method (`default_API`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to do this with actual methods and grabbing the names from the stack frame with that sort of introspection trickery is a recipe for disaster.  Instead, make the "methods" be custom callable objects that know their names.  Here's a sketch:

```
class FakeMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent.send_message(self.name, args, kwargs)

class MainClass(object):
    def build_API(self):
        methods = dict(meth1='arg1', meth2='arg2')
        for key in methods.iterkeys():
            setattr(self, key, FakeMethod(key, self))
    def send_message(self, called_as_name, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Sending message:", called_as_name, args, kwargs)
```

Then:

```
>>> api = MainClass()
>>> api.build_API()
>>> api.meth1()
Sending message: meth1 ((), {}) {}
>>> api.meth2()
Sending message: meth2 ((), {}) {}
```

In theory you could even use `__getattr__` on the MainClass to dynamically generate a FakeMethod every time an attribute name is accessed that is not defined but is listed in some list of API method names.

Comment: Perfect! I thought I needed to somehow store the name with the function, but did not make the leap to use a class object.  "__getattr__" is also a great idea I'll have to try.