# Dynamically adding key-arguments to method

Tags: python, dynamic, methods, named-parameters

I would like to set the default key-arguments of an instance method dynamically. For example, with

```
class Module(object):
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        set-default-key-args-of-method(self.run, kargs)  # change run arguments
    def run(self, **kargs):
        print kargs
```

We would have:

```
m = Module(ans=42)

m.run.im_func.func_code.co_argcount  # => 2
m.run.im_func.func_code.co_varnames  # => ('self','ans','kargs')
m.run.im_func.func_defaults          # => (42,)
m.run()                              # print {'ans':42}
```

I tried something with types.CodeType (which I don't really understand) for a function (not a method) and got it to work (well *not-to-fail*), but the added key-arguments did not show in the kargs dictionary of the function (it only print {})

The change has to be done for the current instance only. Actually, I am using a class right now (I'm OO in my mind) so I would like to do it with a class method, but a function is maybe better. Something like:

```
def wrapped_run(**kargs):
    def run(**key_args):
        print key_args

    return wrap-the-run-function(run, kargs) 

run = wrapped_run(ans=42)

run.func_code.co_argcount  # => 1
run.func_code.co_varnames  # => ('ans','key_args')  ## keep the 'key_args' or not
run.func_defaults          # => (42,)
run()                      # print {'ans':42}
```

Any advise or idea is welcome.

*A little on the context:*

The Module class is some kind a function wrapper, which can be use to include the lower-end function in a dataflow system automatically but add intermediate procedures. I would like the module run function (actually, it will probably be it's __call___ function) to have the correct API in order for the dataflow system to nicely generate the correct module's input transparently.

I'm using python 2.7

Comment: It's worth asking if you want to add the functions to a bound method or an unbound method (e.g. Should they affect only the current instance or every instance of the class?)

Comment: Sooo, you want to have a "pipeline" of functions that can be configured at runtime for data to move through?

Comment: @mgilson, right, it's for the current instance only

Comment: @SpencerRathbun, I develop modules for a dataflow system (OpenAlea) and I want to automatize the wrapping for some special types of functions I made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of closure, I give the only solution that was found: use `exec`
(proposed by **mgilson**)

```
import os, new

class DynamicKargs(object):
    """
    Class that makes a run method with same arguments
    as those given to the constructor
    """
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        karg_repr = ','.join([str(key)+'='+repr(value) \
                              for key,value in kargs.iteritems()])
        exec 'def run(self,' + karg_repr + ',**kargs):\n    return self._run(' + karg_repr + ',**kargs)'

        self.run = new.instancemethod(run, self)

    def _run(self, **kargs):
        print kargs

# this can also be done with a function
def _run(**kargs):
    print kargs

def dynamic_kargs(**kargs):
    karg_repr = ','.join([str(key)+'='+repr(value) for key,value in kargs.iteritems()])
    exec 'def run(' + karg_repr + ',**kargs):\n    return _run(' + karg_repr + ',**kargs)'
    return run


# example of use
# --------------
def example():
    dyn_kargs = DynamicKargs(question='ultimate', answer=42)
    print 'Class example \n-------------'
    print 'var number:', dyn_kargs.run.im_func.func_code.co_argcount
    print 'var names: ', dyn_kargs.run.im_func.func_code.co_varnames
    print 'defaults:  ', dyn_kargs.run.im_func.func_defaults
    print 'run print: ', 
    dyn_kargs.run()
    print ''

    dyn_kargs = dynamic_kargs(question='foo', answer='bar')
    print 'Function example \n----------------'
    print 'var number:', dyn_kargs.func_code.co_argcount
    print 'var names: ', dyn_kargs.func_code.co_varnames
    print 'defaults:  ', dyn_kargs.func_defaults
    print 'run print: ', 
    dyn_kargs()
```

The `example` function prints:

```
Class example 
-------------
var number: 3
var names:  ('self', 'answer', 'question', 'kargs')
defaults:   (42, 'ultimate')
run print:  {'answer': 42, 'question': 'ultimate'}

Function example 
----------------
var number: 2
var names:  ('answer', 'question', 'kargs')
defaults:   ('bar', 'foo')
run print:  {'answer': 'bar', 'question': 'foo'}
```

However:

- there might be problem if arguments value are not well represented by their `repr`
- I think it is too complicated (thus not pythonic), and personally, I did not use it

Answer (score 4):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
class Module(object):
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        old_run = self.run.im_func
        def run(self,**kwargs):
            kargs_local = kargs.copy()
            kargs.update(kwargs)
            return old_run(self,**kargs)
        self.run = run.__get__(self,Module)

    def run(self,**kargs):
        print kargs

m1 = Module(foo=3,bar='baz')
m1.run()
print type(m1.run)

m2 = Module(foo=4,qux='bazooka')
m2.run()
print type(m2.run)
```

I've just created a wrapper instancemethod around the previous function.  (partially inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015307/python-bind-an-unbound-method)).

Alternatively:

```
from functools import partial
from types import MethodType

class Module(object):
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        self.run = MethodType(partial(self.run.im_func,**kargs),self,Module)

    def run(self,**kargs):
        print kargs
```

but this still doesn't give the API you're looking for...

Comment: This answer well with my constraint of being a method but the API is still not correct. The wrapping scheme is interesting.

Comment: @Juh_ -- What exactly do you mean by "The API is not quite correct".  What do you want it to be?

Comment: the co_argcount, co_varnames and so on of the method's function object. A simple test with ipython is doing "m.run?" and having the expected API displayed: m.run(self, foo=3, bar='baz', **kargs)

Comment: @Juh_ -- The only way that I know to do that is to build a string an `exec` it to create the new function.  (that's actually what the `decorator` module does).

Comment: Maybe, this is the way, or maybe I should just not do what I asked... How do you know that this is the behavior of decorator?

Comment: @Juh_ -- I've read the source.  (Note I said "decorator **module**" which is a 3rd party extension).  It should also be pointed out that there is some ambiguity with what you want to do.  dictionaries are *unordered* whereas function arguments are *ordered*.  There's a mismatch there no matter what you do.

Answer (score 3):

`kwargs` is a dictionary, and all we should need to do is save it for later. Then the user can override it with their values.

```
class Module(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.defaults = kwargs
    def run(**kwargs):
        values = dict(self.defaults.items() + kwargs.items())
        print values
```

**EDIT**

Are you perhaps looking for `lambda` function generation?

```
def wrapfunc(**kwargs):
    def run(kwargs):
        print kwargs
    return lambda x: run(dict(kwargs.items() + x.items()))

run = wrapfunc(ans=42)
run({})
run({'ans':12})
```

Comment: @mgilson Because then the defaults override the specifically passed in options.

Comment: My point is not to get default argument in the run method, but to have the run method API suitable for function-wrapping tools

Comment: @SpencerRathbun -- Ahh, right.  Didn't think of that.  (Good answer)

Comment: That is a very simple solution. I'll have to check if lambda can be wrapped into the dataflow system I use. No reason it would not...

Comment: @Juh_ I've got my syntax wrong, at the moment, but the solution itself should hold.

Comment: @Juh_ fixed it. Note that a limitation of lambda functions means that it must have an input value....

Comment: @Juh_ you can edit it to more closely fit the API you desire, but this is about the best python can do for dynamically generating new functions. It's not haskell.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a good idea. Rather than mucking about with function signatures, it would be better to define a set of defaults as an instance variable, and use it in the function:

```
class Module(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.run_defaults = kwargs
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        actual_values = self.run_defaults.copy()
        actual_values.update(kwargs)
        print actual_values
```

Comment: Also, why the copy?  Why not just use `kwargs.update(self.run_defaults)`?  now just use `kwargs` as usual.

Comment: That's the wrong way round: that way defaults would override kwargs, which doesn't seem to be desired.

Comment: My point is not to get default argument in the run method, but to have the run method API suitable for function-wrapping tools