# Binding a method to another class

Tags: python, object, descriptor

```
class A(object):

    def a(self, b=1):
        print 'Up'
    d = {1 : a}

    def b( self ):
        print self.d[1]
        print self.b
        print self.d[1].__get__( self, A )()
        # print self.d[1]()

class B( object ):


    def a( self ):
        print 'here??'
        return 10000
    d = {1 : a}
    def b( self ):
        print 'hurray'

o = A()
o.b()

b = B()
type( o ).__dict__['b'].__get__( b, type( b ) )()
```

Hi Folks,

I was going through [Python: Bind an Unbound Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015307/python-bind-an-unbound-method) and http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm and trying to experiment on my learning.

But, I have hit some new doubts now:-

1. In the last line of my code, I'm able to use `__get__` with `b` object and instance: `type(b)`. This only works if method `b` is defined in `class B`. Why is it so?
2. Even though the last line requires me to provide a method `b` in `class B`, still the method `b` in `class A` gets called. Why is it so?
3. To my utter surprise, after the above step, I notice that the method `a` of `class A` is not called by the code of method `b` of `class A`; instead, it calls the method `a` of `class B`. Why is it so?

I'm quite confused after seeing this behaviour. I might also need to learn more on descriptors. But, it would be a great help if you could answer my doubts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the last line of my code, I'm able to use `__get__` with b object and instance: `type(b)`. This only works if method `b` is defined in `class B`. Why is it so?

You have to define a method `b` in class `B`, because in `A.b` you have `print self.b`. Here, `self` is an instance of the B class, so `self.b` means "the `b` method belonging to this `B`", not "the `b` method belonging to the class that this method exists in". If you delete `print self.b`, then the code will work even if `B` has no `b`.

> Even though the last line requires me to provide a method `b` in `class B`, still the method `b` in `class A` gets called. Why is it so?

`A.b` is being called because you are explicitly accessing it with `type( o ).__dict__['b']`. Whether you bind that method to an A instance or a B instance doesn't matter; it's still `A.b`.

> To my utter surprise, after the above step, I notice that the method `a` of `class A` is not called by the code of method `b` of `class A`; instead, it calls the method `a` of `class B`. Why is it so?

Even though `b` belongs to the class `A`, the `self` you pass to it is still an instance of the `B` class. Any attributes you access on that `self` will be `B` attributes, and any methods you call on it will be `B` methods.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. But, can yout plz explain what could be a real-life example in which we could use `type( o ).__dict__['b'].__get__( b, type( b ) )()` instead of `o.b.__get__( b, type( b ) )()` ? 

In other words, is binding the method `b` of `class A` to `class B` ever possible ? If yes, how and what are the practical use cases of that ?

Comment: "is binding the method b of class A to class B ever possible?" That's exactly what you're doing in your code. Getting `self` to pretend that it's an instance of A is something else entirely. In any case, I don't think there are any practical uses of this. Good OO code shouldn't try to "trick" the environment into thinking an object belongs to a class that it doesn't actually belong to.

Comment: Thanks for answering all my queries.