# a function that modifies its class's data objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to define a function, call it `test_controller()`, and I want to pass this function to a constructor: `my_thing = TestClass(test_controller)`. This function needs to be able to modify its class's data objects. I've heard of the `nonlocal` keyword for Python 3, but I'm running Python 2.7. Is it possible? How do I do this? Here's what I have tried already.

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self, ctrl_func):
        self.a = 4
        self.ctrl_func = ctrl_func

    def do_stuff(self):
        self.ctrl_func()

def test_controller():
    global a
    a = 20

my_thing = TestClass(test_controller)
print my_thing.a         #this prints 4
my_thing.ctrl_func()
print my_thing.a         #this prints 4 but I want it to print 20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in a reference to whatever object you intend to modify.

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self, ctrl_func):
        self.a = 4
        self.ctrl_func = ctrl_func

    def do_stuff(self):
        self.ctrl_func(self)

def test_controller(self):
    self.a = 20

my_thing = TestClass(test_controller)
print my_thing.a         #this prints 4
my_thing.ctrl_func(my_thing)
print my_thing.a         #this prints 4 but I want it to print 20
```

Alternatively, you can convert ctrl_func into a bound method of the object:

```
import types

class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self, ctrl_func):
        self.a = 4
        self.ctrl_func = types.MethodType(ctrl_func, self)

    def do_stuff(self):
        self.ctrl_func()

def test_controller(self):
    self.a = 20

my_thing = TestClass(test_controller)
print my_thing.a         #this prints 4
my_thing.ctrl_func()
print my_thing.a         #this prints 4 but I want it to print 20
```

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1015405/8747
- http://igorsobreira.com/2011/02/06/adding-methods-dynamically-in-python.html

Comment: @Taylor - note change in 2nd example. `types.MethodType()` appears to be preferred over `__get__()`.