# Bind method to self

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this:

```
import concurrent.futures
```

and then in a class method:

```
 self.future = executor.submit(self.listen_for_messages)
```

using JavaScript, we'd have to bind the method to the object instance:

```
 self.future = executor.submit(self.listen_for_messages.bind(self))
```

do we need to do that in Python and if not why not?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need anything like the `bind` call the Javascript code involves. Javascript method binding doesn't work like Python method binding.

In Javascript, when you do `thing.method(stuff)`, formally, the `thing.method` expression resolves to what the standard calls a *Reference*, which carries both the function and the information that `this` should be `thing`. The information about what `this` should be is used when you do `thing.method(stuff)`, but it's discarded if you pass `thing.method` as a callback or do pretty much anything else with it. The `bind` call is needed to preserve the information about `this`.

In Python, instead of the "Reference" stuff, `thing.method` resolves to a bound method object, which carries the information about `self` in the object itself. This information is not discarded, whether you call the method immediately, save it to a variable, pass it to another function as a callback, or do whatever else with it. Nothing like `bind` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling your method `self.listen_for_messages`, which means it's already an *instance method*, bound to `self`. No explicit binding is necessary here.

Just for reference though, you can bind an unbound method as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015307/python-bind-an-unbound-method).