# Replace class method of one specific object

Tags: python, class

Assume class `Man` is defined within third-party file, which is not able to be directly modified:

```
class Man:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def greet(self):
        print(f"Hi, I'm {self.name}.")
```

I want some objects behave differently when called `greet` method.
For example, they speak "Hello" rather than "Hi" when greeting.
There are codes calling `greet` in the third-party file, and I want to change their behaviour.
Here's what I did:

```
def another_greet(self):
    print(f"Hello, I'm {self.name}.")

man = Man("Sue")
man.greet()  # output: "Hi, I'm Sue"
man.greet = another_greet
man.greet()  # TypeError: another_greet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
man.greet(man)  # output "Hello, I'm Sue"
```

However, after the replacing `man.greet = another_greet`, it's not able to call `greet` by `man.greet()`, since the `self` parameter cannot be automatically passed with the object itself. I have to call the method with extra explicit parameter, like `man.greet(man)`, but I can't change the `man.greet()`s in the third party files.

Intuitively I guess there's a way to do it, maybe some tricks on `another_greet` is needed?

Inheritance does solve the question at a certain level. But in practice the object is not declared by me but given by third-party function, so I cannot initialize it as ModifiedMan. Anyway, it's true I can replace it with another ModifiedMan object, taking all its original parameters, yet the practical class is more complex the simply Man and not easy to initialize, doing this introduces much redundant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution, `self` is not being passed automatically because `another_greet` is an **unbound function** unlike `greet` which is a **bound method**. [Python: Bind an Unbound Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015307/python-bind-an-unbound-method) has some solutions to this problem.

To solve your original problem, [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) seems like the proper way to go about; but it also needs the library to provide all the facilities to extend it (from a "usage" perspective). If that is not the case
-- and you are doing it for a non-production usecase -- you can also do "monkey patching" like this:

```
from somewhere import Man

def greet(self):
    print(f"Hello, I'm {self.name}.")

Man.greet = greet
```

I am replacing the function at the **class level** itself so it becomes a **bound method**. I do this a lot in my development environment (like adding logging functionality etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Through [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance), you can extend the functionality of the `Man` class.

Define your own class, and inherit the `Man` class. Then, you can override the `greet()` method, and instances of your new class will use the new definition of `greet()`

```py
class Man:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def greet(self):
        print(f"Hi, I'm {self.name}.")

# This is the class that is inheriting Man.
class ModifiedMan(Man):

    # Redefine the method that you want to override
    def greet(self):
        print(f"Hello, I'm {self.name}."
```

You can read more about inheritance and polymorphism [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polymorphism-in-python/).

Comment: Inheritance does solve the question at a certain level. But in practice the object is not declared by me but given by third-party function, so I cannot initialize it as ```ModifiedMan```. Anyway, it's true I can replace it with another ```ModifiedMan``` object, taking all its original parameters, yet the practical class is more complex the simply ```Man``` and not easy to initialize, doing this introduces much redundant code.

Comment: In that case, I think Nishant's answer is more what you are looking for.