# Can Monkey patching replace existing function definition in a class?

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I know how fierce the SO community is so I'll try my best to keep the question [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

What I simply want to know is can monkey patching be used to replace the definition of an existing function?

for example:

```
class A():

    def foo():
       print '2'

def foo():
    print '5'

A.foo = foo
```

This way doesn't seem to work also as to why I don't just add a new function instead of replacing an existing one, I call these functions in other classes and it is my understanding that monkey patching adds those functions at run-time and I need my python code to run on an Apache spark server which throws an error deeming the calls to that function unreferenced.

So please be nice and help me out or suggest a work around.
Thanks.

**Edit:** The goal of the code is to print 5 when A.foo is called.

Comment: Certainly not with `A.foo = print '5'`, have you tried `A.foo = lambda: print('5')`? (Note that with Python 2 you need to do `from __future__ import print_function`)

Comment: You can see how it's done in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2982/1222951).

Comment: Your code looks quite garbled. Do you want to assign the assignment of a new function called `foo` to `A` when you are calling `foo`?

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for the quick reply could you suggest something for python 2?

Comment: @Nessuno That's what I was intending to get across. In short, I want `A.foo` to print 5

Comment: @Rawing I had previously gone through that answer but I don't want to assign the function to an instance but to the class itself so that answer doesn't really apply to my question. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: @tobias_k Could you take a look at @Rawing 's link. Is it really necessary to use `lambda` here?

Comment: My apologies the earlier example wasn't correct I still intend to print 5 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand what you are trying to do here. This would work in **Python 3**:

```
class A():

  def foo():
     print('2')

def foo():
  A.foo = lambda: print('5')

A.foo() # Print '2'
foo()   # Assign the new method
A.foo() # Prints '5'
```

In **Python 2** however there are several caveats.

- `print` is not a method as it is in Python 3 (see here: [Why doesn't print work in a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970858/why-doesnt-print-work-in-a-lambda))
- You can't just call unbound messages (see here: [In Python, can you call an instance method of class A, but pass in an instance of class B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784331/in-python-can-you-call-an-instance-method-of-class-a-but-pass-in-an-instance-o?noredirect=1&lq=1))

So you have to do it like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class A():

  def foo():
    print('2')

def foo():
  A.foo = lambda: print('5')

A.foo.__func__() # Print '2'
foo()   # Assign the new method
A.foo.__func__() # Prints '5'
```

**Edit:**
After seeing your question in the comment I think you actually want something different. Which is this:

```
class A():

    def foo(self):
       print '2'

def foo(self):
  print '5'

a = A()
a.foo() # Print '2'
A.foo = foo   # Assign the new method
a.foo() # Prints '5'
```

This works just fine in **Python 2**.

The `self` is a reference to the current instance the method is bound to. It is not used when you just call something like `print` which access any properties or methods attached to that instance. But for a different case please have a look at the following example:

```
class A():

    msg = "Some message"

    def foo(self):
       print self.msg


def bar(self):
  self.msg = "Some other message"

a = A()
a.foo() # Print old msg
A.bar = bar   # Assign the new method
a.bar() # Assigns new message
a.foo() # Prints new message
```

Also as chepner points out in a comment under his post:

> The name self isn't special; it's just a convention. You could use
>   this if you really wanted to, and it doesn't need to be the same name
>   in both functions defined here. What is important is that the first
>   argument to a function used as an instance method will be a reference
>   to the calling object. a.foo() is almost exactly the same as A.foo(a)

Comment: Yes, that is what @tobias_k suggested in the comments, but lambda becomes a little inconvenient when defining complex functions. I'm following [this](https://www.codementor.io/jadianes/building-a-web-service-with-apache-spark-flask-example-app-part2-du1083854) tutorial and it does something similar to my example in the question, does that work in python 3? Could it be that the tutorial is in python 3?Since it's isn't explicitly mentioned.

Comment: @VivekShankar This seems of not great importance. As far as I can see this tutorial actually attaches **bound** methods to the class so that they can be called via `a = new A(); a.foo()`. The giveaway is that they actually provide a `self` parameter in the method definition.

Comment: Agreed, but following the way shown in the tutorial and the conventional monkey patching I get `unresolved reference` in PyCharm when I do `a = new A()` and then call it as `a.foo()` .

Comment: Sorry I messed up. It should be `a = A()` please see my latest edit.

Comment: The fact that `print` is a statement in Python 2 just means you can't just a `lambda` expression to define the function. You can still use the `def` statement to wrap `print`, and assign *that* function to `A.foo`.

Comment: @Nessuno Yes, the recent edit is exactly what I want to achieve, could explain why adding `self` argument to the two functions is important here?

Comment: @chepner Yes you are right. It was just that he seemed to be trying to write a class function that attached an unbound method of the same name. That's why I asked if he really wanted to do that in comment to his question.
VivekShankar please have a look at the latest edit.

Comment: @Nessuno Just saw your latest edit, that made everything crystal. Now if my instance is defined in another python file and the reference to `a.bar()` gives _unresolved reference_ how can I fix this?

Comment: You have to import it. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/python-how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory

Comment: @Nessuno I havent added the empty `__init__.py` yet but I'm able to import from that directory and `a = A()` works just fine it is only when I call a function added by the method you suggested above that i get the _unresolved reference error_ particularly at 'a.foo()'.

Comment: My guess is that you moved the code were you are actually monkey patching to a different file. And that file is never executed. Please note that Python is a script language which means that it is not compiled like Java or C. What I guess happens is that the Interpreter has no idea of the method you are trying to append. This means you could either keep all the method definitions you are trying to append in the same file or import the file including functions.

Comment: @Nessuno Thanks, I understand it much better now.

Answer (score 3):

Your only problem is that you aren't defining `foo` correctly in the first place. It needs to take an explicit argument for the instance calling it.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self.x = 2

    def foo(self):
        print(self.x)

def foo(this):
    print(this.x + 3)

A.foo = foo

a = A()
a.foo()  # outputs 5 in Python 2 and Python 3
```

---

In a very real sense, monkey patching is how classes are created in the first place. A `class` statement is almost just syntactic sugar for the following code:

```
def foo(self):
    print(self.x)
A = type('A', (object,), {'foo': foo})
del foo
```

It's not too much of a simplification to image the definition of `type` being something like

```
def type(name, bases, d):
    new_class = magic_function_to_make_a_class()
    new_class.name = name
    new_class.bases = bases
    for k, v in d.items():
        setattr(new_class, k, v)
    return new_class
```

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. I'm new to python, could you please explain why the argument `self` is so important here? Apparently the functions can even have different number of parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now `self` is kinda like the `this` of python.

Comment: The name `self` isn't special; it's just a convention. You could use `this` if you really wanted to, and it doesn't need to be the same name in both functions defined here (I'll edit the answer to demonstrate). What is important is that the *first* argument to a function used as an instance method will be a reference to the calling object. `a.foo()` is almost exactly the same as `A.foo(a)`.