# Unresolved attribute error in PyCharm

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I created a python class for example like:

```
class A():

    def foo(self):
        #Does something

def bar(self):
    #Does some work

A.bar = bar
```

According to my understanding this should add bar to the class.
But when do this in a different class I get the mentioned error

```
global a

a=A()

a.bar() # this gives the error
```

Thanks.

Comment: I know you can do this to an object, but to a class too? I'm not too positive about this.

Comment: @dabadaba Sorry for the late reply, apparently it can be done, please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856154/can-monkey-patching-replace-existing-function-definition-in-a-class/42857445#42857445) SO question and [this](https://www.codementor.io/jadianes/building-a-web-service-with-apache-spark-flask-example-app-part2-du1083854) tutorial I'm looking at. Also I have run and verified the code with the instance in the same class.

Comment: but that's different, because the method with that name already exists. Apparently you cannot just assign `bar` (with a new behavior defined in an external function) to `A` if it is not defined.

Comment: @dabadaba I believe that is what monkeypatching is done for, also as I said in my previous comment the code doesn't give an error if everything is kept in the same file.

Answer (score -1):

Your bar function is outside the class. Correct it:

```
class A():

    def foo(self):
        print('foo')

    def bar(self):
        print('bar')

global a
a = A()
a.bar()
```

Comment: the whole point of what OP is doing is to assign a function that is not initially assigned to the class to that class

Comment: Yes, as @dabadaba said I need the instance and the call to be in another class.

Comment: This code is perfectly working on my system. There is no unresolved attribute error and it adds the method to the class using A.bar = bar